# .zshrc の読み込み時のエラーについて

Tags: macos, pyenv, shell, zsh

こんにちは。

pyenvの環境を構築し直していた際、`source ~/.zshrc` をした際にのみ以下エラーが出るようになってしまいました。(cmd + q でターミナルを終了した後、再度起動した場合にはエラーは出ません。)

```
(eval):5: parse error near `()'
```

環境は macOS Catalina 10.15.2

私の設定ファイルは以下です。

.zshrc

```
export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
PROMPT='%F{6}%c%f $ '

# enable input candidates
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

# add color selected input candidates
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select

# Do not keep the same command history
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS

# zsh pure prompt theme enable -> clear "#" bottom two lines
# autoload -U promptinit; promptinit
# prompt pure

# alias
alias cdd="cd ~/dev"
alias pbc="pbcopy"
alias jl="jupyter lab"
alias v="vim"
alias g="git"
function mkblog() {
  cd "$HOME/dev/blog/";
  hexo new $1;
  vi "./source/_posts/$1.md";
}
alias mkblog=mkblog
alias exa="exa --group-directories-first"
alias ls="ls -G"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

# opam configuration
test -r $HOME/.opam/opam-init/init.zsh && . $HOME/.opam/opam-init/init.zsh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true

# Added by Zplugin's installer
source '$HOME/.zplugin/bin/zplugin.zsh'
autoload -Uz _zplugin
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zplugin]=_zplugin
# End of Zplugin's installer chunk

# add Zplugin's
zplugin light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zplugin light zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

# config starship
eval "$(starship init zsh)"

# cargo path
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"

# binutils
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin:$PATH"

# laravel path setting
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

# Open MPI: Version 2.0.4 path configuration
export PATH="$HOME/opt/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"

# AWS CLI configuration
export PATH="/Users/sk/.local/bin:$PATH"

# cloud_sql_proxy (GCP)
export PATH="/Users/sk/:$PATH"

# pyenv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
alias pyenv="SDKROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path) pyenv"


# auto start tmux
# if [ $SHLVL = 1 ]; then
#   tmux
# fi

# llvm
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc" ]; then . "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc"; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc" ]; then . "$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc"; fi
```

#### 追記

```
❯ pyenv init -
export PATH="/Users/sk/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
export PYENV_SHELL=zsh
source '/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.15/libexec/../completions/pyenv.zsh'
command pyenv rehash 2>/dev/null
pyenv() {
  local command
  command="${1:-}"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command pyenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}

~ 
❯ \pyenv init -
export PATH="/Users/sk/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
export PYENV_SHELL=zsh
source '/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.15/libexec/../completions/pyenv.zsh'
command pyenv rehash 2>/dev/null
pyenv() {
  local command
  command="${1:-}"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command pyenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

#### 追記

再度、状況を検証したところ、ターミナルを起動した直後に `source ~/.zshrc` を行ったときはエラーは出力されず、 `exec $SHELL` 後に `source ~/.zshrc` を実行した際に上記エラーが出ることが判明しました。

原因をご存じの方、ご回答いただけるとありがたいです…

Comment: 「pyenv init -」の実行結果と「\pyenv init -」の実行結果で違いがありますか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

教えていただいたようにコマンドを実行してみたものの、相違ありませんでした…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いったんこの`~/.zshrc`が評価されると、3つの実行可能な`pyenv`が存在します。

- `.pyenv/bin` かどこかにある実行可能ファイル
- `pyenv init -`　の出力を評価して定義されるシェル関数 `pyenv`
- `~/.zshrc` で定義した `alias pyenv`

この2つ目のシェル関数を定義するときに、すでに `alias pyenv` が存在する場合だけ5行目の「`pyenv() {`」がalias展開されて文法エラーになります。

`alias pyenv`の名前を変えるか、`eval`の行の前に`unalias pyenv`しておけば問題なくなるかと思います。